readObject() does not throw exception when the socket is abruptly closed by the remote server. What is the optimal way to find out?
When a client waits for a java object from the server using readObject, we could think that when the server shuts down, it would cause an IOException on the client. But this does not happen, and continues waiting indefinitely on the readObject.
I would like some expert to tell me the better way to model knowing when the server has died, so I can reconnect to it when it revives.

How you expect dead server to notify client that it is dead? You need to setup some sort of timeout. If you not getting response within x second you consider connection dead.

You are perhaps confused about how the internet works. Your client has no way to tell the difference between a server that is simply taking its time sending the data to you, and one that has died. To know that a server has given up entirely / crashed / hung up abruptly, somebody needs to actively send you a packet with the data 'Hello - this server has died'. Given that the server died, it certainly isn't going to do this.
An OS can do this job; notice that the server process has died, and send nice Hangup signals over all the TCP/IP connections that it had before terminating them, but you're now depending on all sorts of behaviours from this server and clearly that isn't happening.
The internet is packet based - what's happening is that some sender has ceased sending packets and there is no way to tell if that means it has died or merely that it is slow.
The usual solution to this problem is timeouts. You make the assumption that 'if no packets arrive in a span of 30 seconds, we just conclude the server has died. Maybe it merely is quite slow but we'll just give up if that is the case; 30 seconds is just too long'. You can set these options on the raw socket with .setSoTimeout, and you can do it yourself by starting a Timer or otherwise managing a 30 second timeout yourself and explicitly calling close() on the underlying InputStream. Then an exception will occur in your readObject code.
